# Geometric/arithmetic sequences: $u_{n+1} = \frac12 u_{n} + 3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I'm having trouble with writing this sequence as a function of $n$ because it's neither geometric nor arithmetic.

> $$\begin{cases}
> u_{n+1} = \frac12 u_{n}  + 3\qquad \forall n \in \mathbb N\\
> u_{0} = \frac13
> \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $$ 2u_{n+1}-u_n = 6 = 2u_n-u_{n-1}$$
so we have $$ 2u_{n+1}-3u_n +u_{n-1}=0$$

Then solving the characteristic equation $2x^2-3x+1=0$ which has a solution $x_1=1$ ans $x_2={1\over 2}$ we get a general solution $$ u_n = a\cdot  1^n +b\cdot \Big({1\over 2} \Big)^n$$

Since $u_1 = {19\over 6}$ by solving a system:

\begin{eqnarray*}
     {1\over 3} &=& a+b\\
 {19\over 6} &=& a+{b\over 2}
\end{eqnarray*}
we get the solution: 
 $$ u_n = 6-{17\over 3\cdot 2^n}$$

Comment: What is the characteristic equation please ?

Comment: You replace $u_n$ with $x^n$ and then you solve $2x^2-3x+1=0$.

Comment: One more question, can you please explain to me how did you write the general solution ?

Comment: Take a look at here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTVTna2jq64 (this is first thing that I found).

Answer (score 6):

Hint. Note that for some real number $a$ (which one?),
$$u_{n+1}-a = \frac12 \left(u_{n}-a\right).$$
Hence, the sequence $(u_n-a)_n$ is of geometric type:
$$u_{n}-a=\frac12 \left(u_{n-1}-a\right)=\frac{1}{2^2} \left(u_{n-2}-a\right)=\dots =\frac{1}{2^{n}} \left(u_{0}-a\right).$$

Comment: Don't forget the $+a$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Similarly to what RobertZ did, turning the arithmetico-geometric recurrence to a purely geometric one, you can get rid of the multiplicative coefficient.

Let $u_n:=\dfrac{v_n}{2^n}$. Then

$$\dfrac{v_{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}=\frac12\dfrac{v_n}{2^n}+3$$ or

$$v_{n+1}=v_n+3\cdot2^{n+1}.$$

This recurrence is now easily solved as a geometric summation

$$v_n=6\,(2^n-1)+\frac13.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $u_m=v_m+a_0+a_1m+\cdots$

$$6=2u_{n+1}-u_n=2v_{m+1}-v_m+a_0(2-1)+a_1(2(m+1)-m)+\cdots$$

Set $a_0=6,a_r=0\forall r>0$

to find $$v_{n+1}=\dfrac{v_n}2=\cdots=\dfrac{v_{n-p}}{2^{p+1}}$$

Now $v_0+6=u_0\iff v_0=?$